Captcha no carga al usar proxy
Utilizo BrightData como proveedor para utilizar proxy al hacer scraping y al cargar el login con captcha no carga el iframe del captcha. no puedo logearme.
con proxy:

Sin proxy:

existe alguna manera o una configuración que este pasando por alto a la hora de considerar el captcha de una pagina al ingresar con proxy?
